# Fetch mysql DB column to list

Tags: python, list

I have to fetch 2 column values to 2 seperate list, I tried below but puts the same column value to both list

```
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT ORDERS,ORDERDATE FROM demo.ORDERS WHERE ORDERSTATUS 
    = 'returned';")    
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    order= [row[0] for row in myresult]
    ORDERDATE= [row[0] for row in myresult]
    print (order)
```

Can you please advice.

Thanks
Yatan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the result set and populate the two lists:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "SELECT ORDERS, ORDERDATE FROM demo.ORDERS WHERE ORDERSTATUS = 'returned';"
mycursor.execute(sql)  
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
order = []
orderdate = []

while myresult:
    for row in myresult: 
        order.insert(len(order), row[0])
        orderdate.insert(len(orderdate), row[1])
```

Comment: HI Tim, I have posted the comment separately.

Comment: @Yatan I updated my answer.  Try using array indices instead of string names.

Comment: I tried using the row[0], but its not returning anything, I believe its going in an infinite while loop.

Comment: Ok, I removed the while myresult: and its working now Thanks.